# Appling a material to selected faces only

Tags: mesh, materials

I looked at this [SO question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162450/how-to-assign-material-to-selected-faces) to apply my material to only one face however the material is applied to the entire mesh.

What have I done wrong?

[image]

Comment: You can split material assignment only if several materials.

Answer (score 3):

As-salamu alaikum !
You have to create a separate material by clicking on the + button. And then select the faces which you want to have the new material, select the new material and click assign. You're done.